# Exemplo para interagir res/xml/prefs.xml com uma atividade.java

Tags: java, android

Por mais que eu tenha procurado, nunca encontrei um exemplo exacto onde interaja um arquivo de preferência com uma atividade em Java, por exemplo:

```
private void Bemvindo(){
Toast.makeText(this, "Seja bem vindo", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
}
```

E no arquivo preferência localizado na pasta res/xml terá esse checkbox:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="true"
                android:key="enable_boasvindas"
                android:title="Mostrar mensagem de boas vindas" />
```

Como faz para o **checkbox** ser mandante?
Se ele tiver marcado, chama o método **Bemvindo** e aparece o *Toast*, caso contrário deixa o método nulo.
Outra coisa; o método **Bemvindo** terá de ser escrito na atividade principal (**MainActivity.java**) ou na atividade de preferência (**Settings.java**)?
Se for na atividade principal, como chama-lo a partir da atividade **Settings**?

Muito obrigado, agradeço desde já! abraços.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para trabalhar com CheckBox, no seu layout crie um CheckBox:

```
<CheckBox
  android:id="@+id/checkBox"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Seu CheckBox"/>
```

Na sua MainActivity, instancie o objeto:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.SEU_LAYOUT_XML);

         checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
         checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             // Se estiver selecionado então mostre a mensagem de boas vindas
             if (checkBox.isChecked()) 
                 benVindo();
           }
        });
    }
    private void bemVindo() {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Seja bem vindo", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Quanto a sua dúvida em deixar o método bemVindo nessa classe ou em uma outra classe, vai de sua preferência (Regra de negócio), caso queira que o método ***bemVindo()*** esteja em outra classe, você deverá chama-lo dessa maneira:

```
 public class Configuracoes {
      public static void bemVindo(Context context) {
           Toast.makeText(context, "Seja bem vindo", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
      } 
 }
```

Agora na sua MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CheckBox checkBox;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.SEU_LAYOUT_XML);

     checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
     checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         // Se estiver selecionado então mostre a mensagem de boas vindas
         if (checkBox.isChecked())
             Configuracoes.bemVindo(MainActivity.this);
       }
    });
}

}
```

Para salvar o "status" do CheckBox use o SharedPreferences desta forma:

```
private void salvar(final boolean isChecked) {
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("check", isChecked);
    editor.commit();
}

private boolean carregar() { 
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check", false);
}

// Você pode associar esse método ao click do botão salvar por exemplo, ou caso não queira
private void salvarStatusCheckBox() {
    save(checkBox.isChecked());
}

// No onResume você carrega o sharedPreferences
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkBox.setChecked(load());
}
```

Comment: Acho que não foi isso que foi perguntado. Ele está falando sobre CheckboxPreference.

Comment: Boooooa mano, muito obrigado. Pensando bem, ao invés de chamar a tela de preferência /xml/prefs.xml, vou criar um layout e seguir este exemplo. Muuuito obrigado. Agora só faltou implementar o SharedPreference pra deixar a opção sempre marcada ou desmarcada, rs. Tu poderias implementar?

Comment: Vou adicionar à minha resposta a parte do SharedPreference. @TechPositivo

Comment: @LeonardoRocha Amigo, nem sei como lhe agradecer. Obrigado de coração. Então, antes de ver sua resposta, eu já havia pesquisado e encontrei um método para salvar o status do checkbox. Tá salvando beleza, mas a mensagem de boas só aparece quando é marcado ou desmarcado a caixinha, ou seja, quando eu fecho e abro o aplicativo novamente não aparece mais. Esse seu código corrigi isso? Especificamente eu acho que é no onResume, né?

Comment: @LeonardoRocha Fiz tudo conforme está escrito! Só que deu a perceber que o método 'onResume' da um reset nas opções marcadas.

Comment: @TechPositivo você quer que a mensagem de "Bem Vindo" seja mostrada apenas em quais momentos?

Comment: @LeonardoRocha Sempre quando o aplicativo é aberto, ou no onResume() mas já conseguir mano. Eu criei vários CheckBox's e coloquei diferentes chaves para cada uma delas. Muito obrigado, você foi super útil.